# why $($var) gives an error?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, command-line, programming

I am trying to execute the following code in shell but I am not getting the output as expected. The command is as follows:

```
i=1
echo $($i)
```

I am getting an error:

```
Command not found error
```

I think it should show the value of the first command line argument, rather it is giving error.

Comment: @steve answers your question nicely, but if you're trying to get access to arguments dynamically, you can look at `$@`, `shift`, `getopts` and bash arrays.

Comment: [Accessing a positional parameter through a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38692603/accessing-a-positional-parameter-through-a-variable)

Answer (score 2):

Because the construct `$(...)` is a [command substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution), so `$($i)` means to run the contents of variable `$i`. In your case, it would try to execute `1`, which the shell cannot find.

See below how it fails, but if we create a script named '1', it works.

Example:

```
$ i=1
$ echo "$($i)"
-bash: 1: command not found  
$ cat >1
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World
$ chmod 755 1
$ PATH=$PATH:`pwd`
$ echo "$($i)"
Hello World
$
```

To display the value of the first command line argument, you need `$1` or `${1}`

```
$ cat >mytest
#!/bin/bash
echo "arg 1 is $1"
echo "arg 1 is ${1}"
$ chmod 755 mytest
$ ./mytest foo
arg 1 is foo
arg 1 is foo
$
```